# Error when activate any TyphoonAssembly

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I'm trying to getting started with Typhoon Framework and I have a problem.

My code is:

```
@interface CustomAssembly : TyphoonAssembly
```

the CustomAssembly don't have more code.

When I run

```
[CustomAssembly new] activate];
```

the app crash with:

> -[CustomAssembly typhoonPropertiesUpToParentClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e86610

How can I fix it? 
What's the problem with this code?

Comment: What version of Typhoon are you using? I was not able to reproduce this with `v3.1.8` or `3.2.1`? Also, have you been using an old version of Typhoon and recently upgraded? Can you try cleaning all contents in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` (or the relevant AppCode dir, if you use that).

Comment: I use the Typhoon pod, updated. And use AppCode but also get the error in Xcode. I will try to clean all contents. Thanks

Comment: Already fixed, thanks @JasperBlues, nice dependency injection framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get the answer.

The problem was that I needed to add Obj-c in "Other linker flags"
I removed this flag when I added Parse framework.